# "quantum mechanical" vs "quantum-mechanical"

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

I'm currently writing a short report, where one (sub-)chapter heading reads:

> The quantum(-)mechanical basics

I am now wondering, whether it is preferable with or without the hyphen. When googling both words in quotation marks, "quantum-mechanical" gets 5.170.000 results, whereas "quantum mechanical" gets 4.990.000 results. Even in the wikipedia-article on Quantum Mechanics, both spellings are used.

Comment: Particle or wave?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's all the same anyways...

Comment: Dunno about ***waves***, but [*a quantum mechanical **particle***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+quantum+mechanical+particle%2Ca+quantum-mechanical+particle&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) usually ***doesn't*** have a hyphen. On the other hand, since that hyphen occurs about in about 1/3 of all written instances in Google Books, it would be a bit much to claim that's actually ***incorrect***.

Comment: A great disservice is done to the questioner, because it is not at all clear how this question relates to the link.

Comment: 'It's all the same anyways...' _exactly_.